# Which tags have the largest proportion of closed questions?

Tags: discussion, closing, statistics

It was already asked [How many questions get closed, and how often are they edited or reopened?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21270/how-many-questions-get-closed-and-how-often-are-they-edited-or-reopened) but I would like to have statistics depending on the tags. I have the feeling that among my favourite tags, some generate more closed questions than other ones, but a numerical evidence would be welcome.

Comment: Perhaps after searching a bit among SEDE queries you might something along the lines what you want: https://www.google.com/search?q=closed+percentage+tag+site%3Adata.stackexchange.com For example, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/449112/percentage-of-closed-questions-by-tag?MinTotal=1000&MaxTotal=10000000) was among the first search results and it seems to return reasonable result. (You can modify parameters to remove tags which are too small.)

Comment: @martin-sleziak Maybe you should convert this very useful comment to an answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [the OP's request](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25362/which-tags-have-the-largest-proportion-of-closed-questions#comment99720_25362) I am expanding my comment a bit and posting it as an answer. (With hope that somebody will post something better.)

[Data Explorer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) might be a useful tool for finding similar statistics. (Although you should keep in mind that the data there are only update once a week.)

For example, there exists the query [Percentage of Closed Questions by Tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/449112/percentage-of-closed-questions-by-tag?MinTotal=1000&MaxTotal=10000000).
(Notice that you can modify parameters to remove tags which are too small.)

Perhaps you can find some other similar SEDE queries.I found this one simply by searching for [closed percentage tag site:data.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=closed+percentage+tag+site%3Adata.stackexchange.com) in Google.